# Google AMP with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, amp-html

I have recently launched an ecommerce site based on laravel. And now i really think its a good idea to implement AMP as it supports ecommerce now (even shopify and ebay are implementing it)

So my query is how can we implement AMP on laravel? Is there a way to use desktopMainTempalte.blade.php for desktop version and switch to mobileMainTemplate.blade.php on mobile version? I just don't want to create a different domain for mobile device as m.domain.com. I want something creative here but Im not sure if i am going in the right direction.

What would you guys be doing if you were in my shoe?

Comment: [This question or one of its answers is being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397721/responding-to-dmca-takedowns).

Comment: Just in case if anyone interested I have written an article on it https://www.google.com/amp/s/stackcoder.in/amp/posts/setup-amp-accelerated-mobile-pages-in-php-laravel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using different routes and controllers to do the same but with a different view is very difficult. You can do this for a better approach.

1. Use the same web controllers for `/amp/` urls
2. View the amp pages differently by modifying `view()` helper

### Amp Routes

To catch the `/amp/` routes, add this to your `RouteServiceProvider.php`

```
protected function mapAmpRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'prefix' => 'amp',
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/web.php');
    });
}
```

Also change your `map` method:

```
public function map()
{
    $this->mapAmpRoutes(); // <-- Add this

    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    $this->mapApiRoutes();
}
```

At this time all addresses like `example.com/amp/...` will refer to your `web.php` routes.

### Amp view files

Now you should customize `view()` helper to render a different view for amp.
Create a `helpers.php` in `app/Http` directory with a view function:

```
function view($view = null, $data = [], $mergeData = [])
{
    $factory = app(Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory::class);

    if (func_num_args() === 0) {
        return $factory;
    }

    //if amp, add '-amp' to view name
    if(request()->segment(1) == 'amp'){
        if(view()->exists($view . '-amp')){
            $view .= '-amp';
        }else{
            abort(404);
        }
    }
    return $factory->make($view, $data, $mergeData);
}
```

This function is not loaded until you add it to your `bootstrap/autoload.php` file

```
require __DIR__.'/../app/Http/helpers.php'; // <-- add this (should be before require vendor/autoload.php)
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

**Edit:** If you don't find `bootstrap/autoload.php` file, search for `vendor/autoload.php` because laravel has removed that. (Thanks *MinderMondo* for the comment)

You can now add any views you like for amp with '-amp' affix. For example if you have `index.blade.php` the amp view name should be `index-amp.blade.php`.

Comment: thanks for this answer. However, a part from it is not working for me. I followed your approach and yes - I am getting the original view but if I have a home url example.com - the amp page would be example.com/amp , if I have example.com/about - it will be example.com/amp/about - and that's great! But the view helper is not fetching the index-amp.blade.php view - it still fetches the old (original view). What could be the problem?

Comment: Oh got it! I am using Laravel 5.6 and I missed to include the helpers.php file. There is no autoload.php in the bootstrap folder. This should be included in vendor/autoload.php instead. This change was made in https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/8914be5fc864ebc6877be38ff3502997e0c62761

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways of implementing AMP pages to your web application (no matter the framework).

One example is the way https://www.theguardian.com have done this : by creating a new sumbomain "amp.theguardian.com" and every page on the main site "www.theguardian.com" has  a canonical link to the same page, but the AMP version and vice versa.

Example : 
Normal page : [LINK](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/commentisfree/2016/feb/16/thomas-piketty-bernie-sanders-us-election-2016)
AMP version of the page : [LINK](https://amp.theguardian.com/us-news/commentisfree/2016/feb/16/thomas-piketty-bernie-sanders-us-election-2016)

As you can see, they are the same, but not quite. Most of the elements that the normal page has are removed from the amp page (because AMP does not allow them or is a bad practice for AMP).

So there you have it! A way to implement AMP to your Laravel project is to have separate views (resources/views/amp) and Controller that handles them.

A good guide to what your AMP views can have as functionalities is [HERE](https://ampbyexample.com/#samples_templates).

Comment: I think theguardian.com way is the best way, isn't it?

Comment: If you create a separate domain then you will end up with 2 source codes which might be harder to maintain in the longer run. I prefer to use the AMP prefix for all the posts. If anyone wondering how did I achieve it kindly check my article https://stackcoder.in/posts/setup-amp-accelerated-mobile-pages-in-php-laravel

Answer (score 0):

I made one site with AMP and my solution was simple adding to routes new GET rule for: `mobile/{articleSlug}/{pageNumber?}`, and new function in Controller to support it, which load all necessary things for new  AMP layout.

If I'm not wrong you can't have AMP page and normal page on this same route - Google will not know how to change between them.

Comment: So what did you do? create a different URL? or domain such as m.domain.com?

Comment: different url for each article in AMP

Comment: I prefer this approach, except I use `/amp/` instead of `/mobile/`.