# How to add amphtml and canonical links for dynamic page views

Tags: php, laravel, amp-html

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53850747/5041759) and [this](https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-amp-optimization) posts to optimize my Laravel site for `Google AMP`. My site shows different `views` for different routes. For example, `/` will open the index page (after binding several views) and `/amp` route will point to an amp version of the index page.

According to [AMP Docs](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/start/converting/discoverable/?format=websites), both pages should be inter-linked by `canonical` and `amphtml` links as:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/article.html">
<link rel="amphtml" href="/article.amp.html">
```

Any idea on giving these links for Laravel blades because I dont have complete `.html` pages. Should I add routes here? e.g.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{{/}}">
<link rel="amphtml" href="{{/amp}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate amp and non-amp pages....copy url from browser and insert those urls accordingly in both links

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).